# Как передать CredHandle дочернему процессу?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, cryptoapi

Добрый день.

Пишу Web-сервер вроде IIS. Реализовал расширения cgi и isapi. По http все великолепно работает. Но с https какие-то траблы возникают.

Я принимаю соединение от браузера, устанавливаю закрытое соединение (рукопожатие), принимают от браузера запрос, декодирую и понимаю, что это клиент isapi. До этого момента всё было гладко.

Web-сервер, принимающий соединения, для работы с isapi, запускает дочерний процесс (который уже загрузит конкретную библиотеку). Это вроде аналогично поведению IIS.

И здесь у меня возникает затруднение. Дочерний процесс получает от родителя сокет и может из него читать и писать в него. Но там данные идут по защищенному соединение. Мне нужен CredHandle клиента как у родительского процесса, что кодировать сообщения для клиента и декодировать сообщения от него.

**Как передать CredHandle дочернему процессу?**

Comment: Что за CreadHandle? Может вам HandleDuplicate поможет?

Comment: CreadHandle - это мандат клиента в рамках https соединения. В нем токен клиента. И он нужен для расшифровки сообщения закодированного клиентом. HandleDuplicate не пробовал, т.к. это какой-то не обычный хендл.